# Action bar in listactivity not showing actions

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar`. When I call

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
```

in my Activity the menu using the `ActionBar`, which is what I want. But when I try this in a `ListActivity`, the menu is added to classic menu (where I have to push the menu button...) How can I add the menu to the `ActionBar` in my `ListActivity`?

Comment: use `showAsAction="always"`

Comment: still not showing in action bar :( I have minSDK 11 and target 14.

Comment: can you post some more code to see what are you doing. like your items.xml, how you implement them in your activity and what is it happening actually and on what kind of device are you testing that.

Comment: menu: http://paste.jabbim.cz/5908 and code: http://paste.jabbim.cz/5909

Comment: im testing on galaxy note2 and emulator with 4.0 android. Problem is propably with ListActivity, which returns a push menu button Inflater, not action bar menu. But i dont know, how solve this problem